# What version of .Net framework should be targeted for end user apps

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a little application in android which would have a server part in .Net (C#). Obviously I want to target maximum number of end users, without having to deal with no framework installed issues.

I was wondering which .Net framework should I target for my app ?
Or which version may I expect to be most definitely there on a user's machine ?

Thanks,

Comment: I'd start from the minimum which your app can run on

Comment: If its a server part in .net then why would you need .net on your user's machines?

Comment: The most used version is 2.0 (3.0 and 3.5 is a superset of 2.0).

Comment: @IanWarburton The client is an android app served by a user's PC/Server where the C# app runs...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Or which version may I expect to be most definitely there on a user's machine ?

This really depends on your user base.

If you want to target all platforms, you can't *guarantee* that any reasonable version will be there, so your deployment should include a check and installation of the framework.  Note that, if you know your user base is typically on Windows 7, for example, you can [guarantee that they'll have .NET 3.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#History), but if some are using XP, there is no guarantee, as no version was included with XP.

Personally, I would just target the version that you wish, and always include a framework installation.  The "cost" of including the check to install the framework, especially if you use the web installer, is very small - much smaller than the development cost of targeting an older framework version and limiting yourself to a less rich development experience.

Comment: Thanks, My target is mainly Windows 7 and Vista users. Does vista come with some pre-installed framework ?

Comment: @user1185422 .NET 3 - though most Vista users typically have 3.5sp1, as Windows Update installs it automatically (unless they opt out)

Comment: Thank you, your answer is quite helpful.